# Multiple SMS activation codes received by error

Tags: authentication, android, multi-factor, sms

For several days now I am receiving activation codes by SMS that look like this:

Your ToYou verification code is 8058

Some are from ToYou, that seems to be a delivery service, others are from similar services in Russia, other are written in Arabic, needless to say I never signed up for these services.

I have been an web developer for over 20 years now and I cannot understand this attack.

This would make some sense to me if they could have access to my phone or they could somehow read the SMS.
The phone seems fine, it's a Samsung Galaxy S10 with everything up to date.
If someone has access to it, it would make more sense to go for the bank accounts, crypto wallets, Google accounts, etc, wouldn't it?

Comment: Someone is trying to sign up using your phone number. It won't work for them unless the site has "verify later" option.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely someone entered your phone number in error when signing up for a service online that uses SMS-based 2FA. Probably safe to just ignore the messages.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case, it's something automated, I have received dozens of messages so far from over 10 services, some of them well known like WhatsApp or Airbnb. There are no links, the messages look like they were legit sent by those services.